# Multiple module nested ui-router with multiple ui-views

Tags: angularjs, uiview, module, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a complex UI architecture based on Angular and Angular UI Router. I'm trying to define routes with nested ui-views on multiple modules.

Here is what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/sxJOPQAgyEZfcYfUReGR?p=preview

Files here:

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <h1 ui-view="title"></h1>
    <div ui-view="sidebar1"></div>
    <ul ui-view="sidebar2"></ul>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router', 'page1'])
.config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider.state({
      name: "page1",
      url: "/page1",
      abstract: true
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
}]);
```

page1.js

```
angular
.module('page1', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'page1.main',
        views: {
            title: {
                template: "My Title"
            },
            sidebar1: {
                template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='item on items'>{{item}}</li></ul>",
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.items = ['foo1', 'bar1'];
                }
            },
            sidebar2: {
                template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='item on items'></li></ul>",
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.items = ['foo2', 'bar2'];
                }
            },
            content: {
                template: "<div ng-repeat='one in many'>{{one}}</div>",
                resolve: {
                    stuff: function () { 
                        return [1,2,3,4,5] 
                    }
                },
                controller: function($scope, stuff) {
                    $scope.many = stuff;
                }
            }
         }
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made few changes, and make it running [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rn7rrkzKFuHdo62nsZtP?p=preview).

Firstly, as defined in doc: [Abstract States](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states), child state of an abstract state must be defined, i.e. must have some url defined *(which will help `ui-router` to find out which state to use... abstract parent is unreachable)*

$stateProvider.state({
            name: 'page1.main',
            url : '/main',

And also the default route was changed to:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1/main');
```

And the most important thing is to use correct `ui-view` naming:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'page1.main',
    url : '/main',
    views: {
            "title@": {
                template: "My Title"
            },
            "sidebar1@": {
                template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='item on items'>{{item}}</li></ul>",
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.items = ['foo1', 'bar1'];
                }
            },
            "sidebar2@": {
                template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</li></ul>",
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.items = ['foo2', 'bar2'];
                }
            },
            "content@": {
            ...
```

What we can see, the view names are suffixed with the `@`, which means: search for them in the top root, unnamed view (usually index.html)

See more here: [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

a small extract from doc:

```
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //
    // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.
    // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html
    "info@contacts.detail" : { }

    // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
    "detail@contacts" : { }

    // Absolutely targets the unnamed view in parent 'contacts' state.
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
    "@contacts" : { }
```

The working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rn7rrkzKFuHdo62nsZtP?p=preview).

EDIT: How to preserve the `/page1` in url

As *(almost)* always with `ui-router`, we can give us this behaviour. The trick is, to reset url evaluation to start on the root level - even for child *(without parent url part)*. And this could be done with a magical "`^`" sign

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'page1.main',
    url : '^/page1',
    views: {
       ....
```

Here is doc:

- [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-) `(a cite)`

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.
>   
>   Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cEHoIXIJSgPCRXK7t3LZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot Radim. I understand completely where I messed up. Just a comment regarding your changes: I really need to access page1 as /page1 and there should be defined in two different modules. Perhaps I should had clarify that from the beginning.

Comment: In that sense, the otherwise instruction should remain "/page1" and the `page1.main` state should have an empty url.

Thanks again Radim for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: If I understand your issue properly... the udpated answer should give you clear answer ;)